# for loops in reacts js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update this values, but whenever I `console.log` it's always `0`, even if the conditions is true.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

interface orderInformation {
  customer: number;
  picklePrice: number;
  breadPrice: number;
}

interface ComponentState {
  customer: number;
  picklePrice: number;
  breadPrice: number;
  error: string;
  finalPickleCost: number;
  finalBreadCost: number;
  pickleCounter: number;
  breadCounter: number;
}

export default class pickleSandwich extends Component<
  orderInformation,
  ComponentState
> {
  constructor(props: orderInformation) {
    super(props);

    //initializing variables to undefined
    this.state = {
      customer: 0,
      picklePrice: 0,
      breadPrice: 0,
      finalBreadCost: 0,
      finalPickleCost: 0,
      pickleCounter: 0,
      breadCounter: 0,
      error: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  //Get information for the user
  getInfo = orderInformation => {
    orderInformation.preventDefault();

    const { customer, picklePrice, breadPrice } = this.state;
    console.log("customer", customer);
    console.log("pickle", picklePrice);
    console.log("bread", breadPrice);
    if (customer > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < customer; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
          this.setState({
            pickleCounter: this.state.pickleCounter + 2,
            breadCounter: this.state.breadCounter + 3
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            pickleCounter: this.state.pickleCounter + 1,
            breadCounter: this.state.breadCounter + 2
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        error: "Please enter amount of customer"
      });
    }
    console.log("pickle Counter", this.state.pickleCounter);
    console.log("breadCounter", this.state.breadCounter);
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value } as any);
  };

  render() {
    // const { customer, finalPickleCost, finalBreadCost } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.getInfo}>
        <p>Get the information of the order!</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="customer"
          value={this.state.customer}
          placeholder="Amount of Customers"
          name="customer"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          required
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          id="picklePrice"
          placeholder="Price of Pickle"
          value={this.state.picklePrice}
          name="picklePrice"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          required
        />

        <input
          type="text"
          id="breadBrice"
          placeholder="Price of Bread"
          value={this.state.breadPrice}
          name="breadPrice"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.getInfo}>
          Get Information{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I want it to update the values, so I can calculate the final cost.

Answer (score 4):

React's `setState` is asynchronous, meaning by the time you reach your `console.log` the state might not have updated yet.

Refer to the [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value) and [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more information on this behavior and `setState` in general.

To circumvent this issue, you could use `setState`'s callback method, which is fired once the state update was performed:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    pickleCounter: prevState.pickleCounter + 1,
    breadCounter: prevState.breadCounter + 2
}), () => {
    // once you're here the state updated successfully
});
```

Comment: You know, I like this answer more than mine.  For some reason I never made the thought to use async/await for setState.

Comment: @ChrisSandvik It wont matter, `this.setState` doesn't `return` a `Promise` so you can't `await` for it.

Comment: @AsafAviv you are right. I had to read up on the subject and was baffled. I was 100% sure that you could await `setState`. Thanks for pointing it out, going to have to change some things once I get back to work on Monday. *The more you know*

Comment: @ChrisSandvik First part per docs shouldn't work, so I removed it. Just keep using the callback and you should be fine!

Comment: @ChrisSandvik You can only `await` for a function if it returns a `Promise`,  `await` create a one tick delay.

Comment: @TobiasTengler check my updated answer, I found a way to actually use your initial suggestion in a nice fashion I believe!

Answer (score 0):

Setting state is an asynchronous function so the new state is generally not accessible if called within the same function, unless you use a callback for the `setState` function:

```
this.setState({...content...}, callbackFunction)
```

**EDIT**

Using something Tobias originally mentioned that did not work as he described gave me an idea.  One way to use async await in this instance would be to add a custom function to make setState return a promise.

```js
setStateAsync(state) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.setState(state, resolve)
    });
}
```

You can use this to make your function wait for the state to be set.

```js
setStateAsync(state) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.setState(state, resolve)
  });
}

//Get information for the user
getInfo = async orderInformation => {
  orderInformation.preventDefault();

  const {
    customer,
    picklePrice,
    breadPrice
  } = this.state;
  console.log("customer", customer);
  console.log("pickle", picklePrice);
  console.log("bread", breadPrice);
  if (customer > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < customer; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 0) {
        await this.setStateAsync({
          pickleCounter: this.state.pickleCounter + 2,
          breadCounter: this.state.breadCounter + 3
        });
      } else {
        await this.setStateAsync({
          pickleCounter: this.state.pickleCounter + 1,
          breadCounter: this.state.breadCounter + 2
        });
      }
    }


  } else {
    await this.setStateAsync({
      error: "Please enter amount of customer"
    });
  };
  console.log("pickle Counter", this.state.pickleCounter);
  console.log("breadCounter", this.state.breadCounter);
};
```

Comment: I am currently learning React and I am doing this as a practice, would you mind giving a quick explanation about the callbackFunction, and how to use it.?

Comment: A callback function is just any function you want to run after the state is set.  So in your case, it might not be the proper solution because your output is case dependent.  Can you post a longer chunk of your code so I can see how you’re trying to use it?

Comment: added it as an answer

Comment: @DanielIsaacChavez check my updated answer, I believe it is the simplest solution to your problem

Comment: Your edit is definitely interesting, but would be too hacky for me. ^^

Comment: I wouldn't really call it "hacky" but it definitely isn't a standard way to go about things haha

Comment: Either way, its a little simpler than adding a callback to every setState call within the function considering there are multiple routes it can take

Comment: I get this error message Property 'setAsyncState' does not exist on type 'pickleSandwich'.  TS2339

Comment: @DanielIsaacChavez oops, I mixed up the order of the words when calling the function, should be `setStateAsync`.  I updated my answer again to be correct.

Comment: that worked! Thank you, do you recommend every time I am using setState in a case like this use this method?

Comment: I wouldn’t say this is the best answer regardless of the scenario, but in places where you have multiple different paths the stage can be set inside of in the same function, and then later need to access those values in that function, this is a pretty succinct way to accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

React `setState()` may be asynchronous, which means updating one value and consoling it after may give you the old data, doing the following is wrong

```
// wrong, anti-pattern
this.setState({
  pickleCounter: this.state.pickleCounter + 2,
  breadCounter: this.state.breadCounter + 3
});
```

A better way

> setState(updater[, callback])

```
//  good
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return { 
    pickleCounter: prevState.pickleCounter + 2,
    breadCounter: prevState.breadCounter + 3
  }
});
```

**Working example**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  //initializing variables to undefined
  state = {
    customer: 0,
    picklePrice: 0,
    breadPrice: 0,
    finalBreadCost: 0,
    finalPickleCost: 0,
    pickleCounter: 0,
    breadCounter: 0,
    error: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    );
  };

  //Get information for the user
    getInfo = async (orderInformation) => {
    orderInformation.preventDefault();

    const { customer, picklePrice, breadPrice } = this.state;
    console.log("customer", customer);
    console.log("pickle", picklePrice);
    console.log("bread", breadPrice);
    if (customer > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < customer; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
          await this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
              pickleCounter: prevState.pickleCounter + 2,
              breadCounter: prevState.breadCounter + 3
            }
          }, () => {
            console.log("pickle Counter", this.state.pickleCounter);
            console.log("breadCounter", this.state.breadCounter);
          });
        }
        else {
         await this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
              pickleCounter: prevState.pickleCounter + 1,
              breadCounter: prevState.breadCounter + 2
            }
          }, () => {
            console.log("pickle Counter", this.state.pickleCounter);
            console.log("breadCounter", this.state.breadCounter);
          });
        }
      }


    } else {
      this.setState({
        error: "Please enter amount of customer"
      });
    };
  };
  
  render() {
    // const { customer, finalPickleCost, finalBreadCost } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.getInfo}>
        <p>Get the information of the order!</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="customer"
          value={this.state.customer}
          placeholder="Amount of Customers"
          name="customer"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          required
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          id="picklePrice"
          placeholder="Price of Pickle"
          value={this.state.picklePrice}
          name="picklePrice"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          required
        />

        <input
          type="text"
          id="breadBrice"
          placeholder="Price of Bread"
          value={this.state.breadPrice}
          name="breadPrice"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.getInfo}>Get Information </button>

      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

You can pass a callback to `setState`, which will be called after setState finishes setting state.

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  pickleCounter: prevState.pickleCounter + 2,
  breadCounter: prevState.breadCounter + 3
}, () => {
  // code here
});
```

Or use async/await

```
await this.setState({...})
```

**Async/Await example**

without async/await, state may be asynchronous.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    name: 'React'
  };


  componentDidMount = () => {

    this.setState({
      name: 'Peter'
    });

    console.log('logs old value: ', this.state.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

**With async/await**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

    class App extends React.Component {

      state = {
        name: 'React'
      };


      componentDidMount = async () => {

        await this.setState({
          name: 'Peter'
        });

        console.log('logs new value: ', this.state.name);
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{this.state.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
```

Please see the following docs.

[State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

You could update values like this

```
if(i%3 === 0)
{
  this.setState((prevState)=>{
    return {
      pickleCounter: prevState.pickleCounter + 2,
      breadCounter:  prevState.breadCounter + 3
    }

  });
}
```

Here, inside `this.setState()` instead of just providing new state we are providing a function that returns new state and in this way, we have access to old state. You can choose any variable name instead of `prevState` for previous state.

Comment: this is still now working, values are not updating.

Comment: are you updating customer count ? check how many customer you have may be you would find bug.